# Angular Rendering

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following components...

**post-single.component.html**

```html
<section class="notes" [innerHTML]="post.notes | unmark "></section>
<section class="notes">
    <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt felis vel varius sagittis. Donec interdum lacus mauris. Vestibulum consectetur mauris id diam aliquet, sit amet facilisis eros fringilla.</li>
        <li>Praesent facilisis mollis nunc, eu bibendum metus dictum et. Praesent sagittis malesuada facilisis. Proin eu nunc erat. Nunc dignissim magna eu posuere volutpat. Duis commodo, nulla vel convallis rutrum, enim ex posuere lectus.</li>
        <li>Aliquam elementum, neque a vulputate vulputate, neque nisi interdum enim, eu suscipit elit tortor tempor mauris. Proin tempor purus luctus, vulputate odio ut, ultricies lacus. Integer ultrices, nunc sit amet elementum faucibus, magna mauris vulputate lorem, sed posuere felis mi porttitor ligula.</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

**`post.notes` Object**

```json
{
   notes: '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt felis vel varius sagittis. Donec interdum lacus mauris. Vestibulum consectetur mauris id diam aliquet, sit amet facilisis eros fringilla.\n2. Praesent facilisis mollis nunc, eu bibendum metus dictum et. Praesent sagittis malesuada facilisis. Proin eu nunc erat. Nunc dignissim magna eu posuere volutpat. Duis commodo, nulla vel convallis rutrum, enim ex posuere lectus.\n3. Aliquam elementum, neque a vulputate vulputate, neque nisi interdum enim, eu suscipit elit tortor tempor mauris. Proin tempor purus luctus, vulputate odio ut, ultricies lacus. Integer ultrices, nunc sit amet elementum faucibus, magna mauris vulputate lorem, sed posuere felis mi porttitor ligula.'
}
```

**post-single.component.scss** (relevant portion)

```css
:host {
    main > div > div.container {
        section.notes {
            & > ol {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;

                li {
                    padding-left:22px;
                    text-indent: -22px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**rendered HTML***

```html
<section _ngcontent-xwv-c22="" class="notes">
    <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt felis vel varius sagittis. Donec interdum lacus mauris. Vestibulum consectetur mauris id diam aliquet, sit amet facilisis eros fringilla.</li>
        <li>Praesent facilisis mollis nunc, eu bibendum metus dictum et. Praesent sagittis malesuada facilisis. Proin eu nunc erat. Nunc dignissim magna eu posuere volutpat. Duis commodo, nulla vel convallis rutrum, enim ex posuere lectus.</li>
        <li>Aliquam elementum, neque a vulputate vulputate, neque nisi interdum enim, eu suscipit elit tortor tempor mauris. Proin tempor purus luctus, vulputate odio ut, ultricies lacus. Integer ultrices, nunc sit amet elementum faucibus, magna mauris vulputate lorem, sed posuere felis mi porttitor ligula.</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section _ngcontent-xwv-c22="" class="notes">
    <ol _ngcontent-xwv-c22="">
        <li _ngcontent-xwv-c22="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt felis vel varius sagittis. Donec interdum lacus mauris. Vestibulum consectetur mauris id diam aliquet, sit amet facilisis eros fringilla.</li>
        <li _ngcontent-xwv-c22="">Praesent facilisis mollis nunc, eu bibendum metus dictum et. Praesent sagittis malesuada facilisis. Proin eu nunc erat. Nunc dignissim magna eu posuere volutpat. Duis commodo, nulla vel convallis rutrum, enim ex posuere lectus.</li>
        <li _ngcontent-xwv-c22="">Aliquam elementum, neque a vulputate vulputate, neque nisi interdum enim, eu suscipit elit tortor tempor mauris. Proin tempor purus luctus, vulputate odio ut, ultricies lacus. Integer ultrices, nunc sit amet elementum faucibus, magna mauris vulputate lorem, sed posuere felis mi porttitor ligula.</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

**NOTE:** the `unmark` pipe uses the `marked` npm package to convert markdown to HTML.

**My Issue**

The issue is that the style is **not** applied to the first, dynamic `<ol />` (the one that's being converted from markdown into HTML), but it is applied to the second, "hardcoded" one.

Why is that? I assume it has something to do with how it's being tracked, maybe? But, more importantly, how do I fix it so that the style is correctly applied?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for `:ng-deep`

Comment: Try to see how the generated CSS looks like. Maybe this will give you some clues.

Comment: @tromgy the css works fine on the hard coded because the `_ngcontent-xwv-c22` selector is added automatically to the css. Why isn’t the attribute added in the first order list and list items?

Comment: Yes, I suspected something like that. I guess it's not added because content is not generated by Angular, but by unmark. Setting `innerHTML` directly likely circumvents any Angular processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an `HtmlDirective`:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[html]',
})
export class HtmlDirective implements OnChanges {
  private _uniqueId!: string;

  @Input()
  public html!: string;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _router: Router) {}

  public ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.html) {
      this._uniqueId ||= [...this._elementRef.nativeElement.attributes].find(
        (attr) => attr.name.startsWith('_ngcontent-')
      ).name;

      this._elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.html;

      const descandants = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('*');

      for (const element of descandants) {
        element.setAttribute(this._uniqueId, '');

        if (element.tagName === 'A') {
          const href: string = element.href?.toLowerCase();

          if (href?.startsWith(location.origin.toLowerCase())) {
            element.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
              this._router.navigate([href.substring(location.origin.length)]);
              e.preventDefault();
            });
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = null;
    }
  }
}
```